# How to implement Builder Pattern in java @Test?

Tags: java

I need to write an implementation to a given unit test, that cannot be changed.

```
/**
 * This is the car factory test. For all the tests to succeed, the implementations and the classes you
 * think might be required, would have to be written.
 *
 * Existing tests cannot be modified unless you notice an error.
 * You are free to create new tests in order to increase the coverage.
 *
 * The purpose of this exercise is to see the quality of the code written, how it is structured.
 *
 * A car factory build several car models using parts: engine, tires and chassis.
 * All car parts have a quality level between 1 and 5 (inclusive). 1 being the lowest, 5 the highest.
 *
 * Cars have 4 external characteristics: top speed, acceleration, manoeuvrability and braking.
 * Top speed is an integer expressed in kilometers per hour
 * Acceleration is a string representation of a java.time.Duration: this is the time it takes for the vehicle to reach 100 km/h
 * Manoeuvrability is an integer representing the maximum number of degrees the vehicle can turn at 50 km/h without drifting
 * Braking is an integer that represents the number of meters it takes to stop the vehicle when going at 50 km/h
 *
 * Each level of "engine":
 *  - adds 30 km/h in top speed
 *  - removes 2s to the acceleration
 * Each level of "tires":
 *  - removes 10% to the acceleration
 *  - adds 10 degrees to the manoeuvrability
 *  - removes 10% to the braking distance
 * Each level of "chassis":
 *  - adds 5% to the top speed
 *  - adds 0.25s to the acceleration
 *  - adds 5 degrees to the manoeuvrability
 *  - adds 5 meters to the braking distance.
 *
 *  Warning: all fixed-number impacts (like for top speed and braking) are applied before any percentage modifications granted by other parts.
 */
public class AppTest {
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testFactoryCannotBuildIncompleteCars() {
        CarFactory carFactory = new CarFactory();
        carFactory.withEngine(1);

        carFactory.build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testModel1Creation() {
        CarFactory carFactory = new CarFactory()
            .withEngine(1)
            .withTires(1)
            .withChassis(1);

        Car model1 = carFactory.build();
        assertNotNull(model1);
    }

    /**
     * This test also gives the base characteristics of cars
     */
    @Test
    public void testModel1Characteristics() {
        CarFactory carFactory = new CarFactory()
                .withEngine(1)
                .withTires(1)
                .withChassis(1);

        Car model1 = carFactory.build();
        assertEquals(100, model1.topSpeed());
        assertEquals("PT15S", model1.acceleration());
        assertEquals(20, model1.manoeuvrability());
        assertEquals(50, model1.braking());
    }

    @Test
    public void testModel2Characteristics() {
        CarFactory carFactory = new CarFactory()
                .withEngine(2)
                .withTires(1)
                .withChassis(1);

        Car model1 = carFactory.build();
        assertEquals(130, model1.topSpeed());
        assertEquals("PT12S", model1.acceleration());
        assertEquals(20, model1.manoeuvrability());
        assertEquals(50, model1.braking());
    }

    @Test
    public void testModel3Characteristics() {
        CarFactory carFactory = new CarFactory()
                .withEngine(5)
                .withTires(5)
                .withChassis(5);

        Car model1 = carFactory.build();
        assertEquals(264, model1.topSpeed());
        assertEquals("PT4.2S", model1.acceleration());
        assertEquals(80, model1.manoeuvrability());
        assertEquals(42, model1.braking());
    }
}
```

I created the Builder Pattern to satisfy that requirement. but you cannot create the Builder inner class without to instiate outer class first.

```
package com.example;

import java.time.Duration;

public class Car {
    private Integer topSpeed;
    private Duration acceleration;
    private Integer manoeuvrability;
    private Integer braking;

    public Car(CarFactory carFactory) {
    }

    public static class CarFactory {
        private Integer topSpeed;
        private Duration acceleration;
        private Integer manoeuvrability;
        private Integer braking;

        public CarFactory(Integer topSpeed, Duration acceleration, Integer manoeuvrability, Integer braking) {
            this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
            this.acceleration = acceleration;
            this.manoeuvrability = manoeuvrability;
            this.braking = braking;
        }

        public CarFactory withEngine(Integer levels) {
            for (int index = 0; index < levels; index++) {
                this.acceleration = this.acceleration.minusSeconds(2);
                this.acceleration = this.acceleration.minusSeconds(2);

            }
            return this;
        }

        public CarFactory withTires(Integer levels) {
            for (int index = 0; index < levels; index++) {
                this.manoeuvrability = this.manoeuvrability + 10;
                this.acceleration = this.acceleration.minusSeconds(2);
                this.braking = this.braking + 5;

            }
            return this;
        }

        public CarFactory withChassis(Integer levels) {
            for (int index = 0; index < levels; index++) {
                this.topSpeed = (int) (this.topSpeed + (topSpeed * 0.05));
                this.acceleration = this.acceleration.plusMillis(25);
                this.manoeuvrability = this.manoeuvrability + 5;
                this.braking = this.braking + 5;

            }
            return this;
        }

        public Car build() {
            return new Car(this);
        }
    }
}
```

as the Builder pattern should use an inner static Builder class. My question is how can I instantiate the Builder without referencing the outer class as required in the unit test?

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically you could import it:

```java
import com.example.Car.CarFactory;
```

However, you indicated you can't change the test code, presumably not even to add imports. If this is indeed the case, it means that `Carfactory` should be its own top-level class, and not an inner class inside `Car`.